# Virtual Hosts w/ IIS 7.5.x Not Paying Attention to Path

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis, virtualhost

I have setup numerous linux web servers (using Apache) but I am new to IIS.  I am trying to setup two new vhosts, let's call them vhost1.domain.com and vhost2.domain.com for the purposes of this example.

I have added two new sites, one for each vhost and set their path to specific (and unique) directories.  Unfortunately when I pull the site up via vhost1.domain.com I just get the default IIS page saying:

> It Works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

It seems that they aren't paying attention to their proper path.

Something worth noting is that I just installed PHP 5.3 on the server (Windows Server 2008) and I used the Microsoft Web Platform Installer to do so.  Everything went smoothly and I used all default settings.

If I need to supply more information/details please let me know, any insight that can be provided would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that IIS was setup correctly and the problems I was having were all related to DNS.  Once we got the DNS stuff straightened out everything came together.